# How do primary alcohols react with dihydropyrans

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

Can anyone also explain me the mechanism of this reaction?

[image]

I think it might be formation of acetal or hemiacteal reaction but I am not sure about it.

Comment: Why do you consider a the formation of  a *hemiacetal* under anhydrous conditions?

Comment: @KlausWarzecha sir actually I don't know. I am just having a guess because I think ester or ether will not formed from this reaction. Can you please explain me the mechanism and the product?

Answer (score 4):

Please have a closer look at your starting materials and the reaction conditions.

1. The reaction is performed under protic, ahydrous conditions.
2. One of the starting materials is a primary alcohol.
3. The other starting material apparently looks like a cyclohexene where one carbon adjacent to the $\ce{C=C}$ double bond has been replaced by an oxygen atom. This is a dihydropyrane.

Now, let's try a mind game:

1. Supposed that your second starting material is cyclohexene, what would happen under anhydrous, protic conditions?

   > The proton would probably add to the $\ce{C=C}$ double bond to form a cyclohexyl cation. Since the starting material is symmetric, there is only one secondary cation formed. Note that the situation would be different if you would start with methylcyclohexene! Then, a secondary or a tertiary cation could be formed. Remember inductive effects to judge which one is favoured.
2. How would the primary alcohol come into play here?

   > It would probably add to the cyclohexyl cation and yield an ether.
3. In reality, your second starting material is a dihydropyrane, think *cyclic vinyl ether*. How will the lone pairs on the oxygen atom effect the protonation?

   > If in doubt, draw! Your $\ce{C=C}$ double bond now has two markedly different carbon atoms. Protonation can result in two different cations. I suggest to draw some resonance structures to figure out which one is favoured. Remember the lone pairs ;-)
4. What happens in the presence of a primary alcohol now?

   > Again, it will add to the cation.
5. How does the final structure look like?

   > I'm certain that you have figured this out by drawing and once you have, you will easily identify the structure class :)

Note that the reaction in question is quite useful to reversibly protect alcohols in sequences of chemical transformations.